# Angular $mdToast - two way data binding not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've made a simple `$mdToast` for my app, but its not displaying the value of my variable even thought I've used `$scope.$apply()`.

**JS code:**

```
somePromise.then((response) => {
    $scope.$apply(() => {
        $scope.message = response.data;
        $mdToast.show({
            'controller': 'MainController',
            'templateUrl': `templates/notifications/success_noti.html`,
            'hideDelay': 5000
        });
    });
});
```

btw, I'm using pug (known as jade before).
Template - **success_noti.pug**

```
md-toast
    span(flex) {{message}}
    md-button(ng-click="closeToast()") OK
```

Comment: you aren't showing enough code to know for certain what is going on, but what it looks like is that you are setting `$scope.message` in some other controller other than the instance the `$mdToast` is using.  Even if the controller name is the same, that just means they are sharing the same *code*, not the same *instance*.

Comment: No, I'm using all of this inside a single controller, `MainController`.
The weird thing is if I put `$scope.message` outside the promise, lets say, at the beginning of `MainController` and set its value to just a string, then it will work properly.

Comment: right, you have two instances of `MainController`.  one for the page, and a second that is created by `$mdToast.show`.  the second instance doesn't have access to the dynamic variables of the first instance.

Comment: it's not weird that setting the value in the controller's constructor makes the message show, though it's not really "working properly"; each new instance of the controller would run the constructor, and initialize that string value.  however, if you were to change the value on your page, the toast would still show the value it initialized, not the changed value.

Comment: even though the controllers are sharing the same code (being initialized from the same controller file), they still are two separate controller instances, and you would need a service in order to exchange data between the two instances.  In practical use, it's actually better to use completely different controllers, to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: hmmm, I think I get the idea.
thanks!

Comment: services (and all other providers) are singletons, provided to controllers through dependency injection.  controllers, on the other hand, are not singletons, and that is a source of confusion when first starting out with angular.